# Getting nested form to work rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have these models:

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :list_items, :dependent => :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :list_items, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a(:task.blank?)}
end

class ListItem < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :list
end
```

and this controller:

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @lists = List.order("lists.created_at DESC")
  end

  def show
    @list = List.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @list = List.new({:name => Time.now.strftime("%A %d %B")})
    3.times { @list.list_items.build}
  end

  def create
    @list = List.new(list_params)

    if @list.save
      flash[:notice] = "List successfully added."
      redirect_to(:action => 'index')
    else
      render(:action => 'new')
    end
  end

  def edit
    @list = List.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @list = List.find(params[:id])

    if @list.update_attributes
      flash[:notice] = "List updated successfully."
      redirect_to(:action => 'index')
    else
      render(:action => 'edit')
    end
  end


  def delete
    @list = List.find(params[:id])
  end

  def destroy 
    @list = List.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:notice] = "List successfully deleted"
    redirect_to(:action => 'index')
  end

  private
  def list_params
    params.require(:list).permit(:name, :task)
  end

end
```

and this form:

```
<%= form_for @list do |f| %>

<p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
</p>
    <%= f.fields_for :list_items do |builder| %>
        <p>
            <%= builder.label :task %><br />
            <%= builder.text_field :task %>
        </p>

    <% end %>
    <p><%= f.submit "Create" %></p>
<% end %>
```

You can probably see what I am trying to do -> create a form where it creates a new list and then adds task to that list but for some reason whenever I hit submit on the form the name stays but tasks don't save?

Comment: Inspect incoming `params` to lists#create action. What do they look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem turns out i needed to add the list_item attributes to the list controller. I was trying to do this the rails 3 way in teh model with attr_accessible which kept giving me an error. I needed to update the controller to have this at the bottom:

```
def list_params
    params.require(:list).permit(:name, :list_items_attributes => :task)
  end
```

Comment: BTW something which will help a lot is [simple_form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) - this will make a lot of this process DRY for you